Is it passive or honorific? 「私が足止めすれば二乃に気づかれない。」
For bit of context, in Quintessential Quintuplets chapter 65, Nino requested Ichika to keep watch on their father so she can sneak out.

There is one sentence I have trouble with:

もし私たちの部屋に来ようととても私が足止めすれば二乃に気づかれない

I can't tell whether 二乃に気づかれない is honorific or (suffering) passive. It either means "father won't notice Nino" or "I won't get to have father to notice Nino."

It's suffering (indirect) passive. Generally, only characters who use stereotypical お嬢様 speech use honorific language to their parents.
Note that, unlike 雨に降られた or 親に死なれた, this に marks not the subject of 気づく but the target of 気づく. That is, "父親が二乃に気づく (Father notices Nino)" is the undesirable event that negatively affects the two girls.

私が足止めすれば、(父親に)二乃に気づかれない
If I stop him here, Father won't notice Nino.

